# Can someone please help me figure how to convert these measurements I am doing in practice problems?

Tags: unit-of-measure

I am trying to figure out how to convert these measurements and I don't know how. Can someone help me out?

1. 456.8 cm3 = ___________ L
2. 1.9 hg = ____________ cg
3. 12.345 m = ________ mm
4. How many kiloliters are in 15.0 deciliters?
5. How many centigrams are in 22.65 grams?
6. How many millimeters are in 1500.0 meters?

Comment: $456.8$ cm$^3\times \dfrac {1 L}{1000 \text{ cm}^3}=0.4568 L$

Comment: Write out your unit conversions and explain where you are struggling.

Comment: The last three follow from the definitions of dec, kilo, cent and mili. Write out these as well.

Comment: Type them into google and it will convert them for you. So for example "456.8cm^3 in L"

Answer (score 1):

These are all measurements in metric units, so conversion is simply a matter of multiplying or dividing by the appropriate power of 10. The prefixes and scaling factors can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

So for example 1 hg (hectogram) = 100 g  and 1 g = 100 cg (centigrams).

Therefore 1.9 hg = 190 g = 19,000 cg.

Use the same approach for the rest.